# How to use google charts and set the document.domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-visualization

It seems that changing the document.domain property causes Google Charts to not work in Internet Explorer (at least version 8). Below is a very simple page that demonstrates the problem. The example code is almost straight from the Google Charts library sandbox. The only  major difference is that I added a prior JavaScript that sets the document.domain.

We are working on a subdomain, say "test.example.com", and we need, for other reasons, to set the document.domain property to just "example.com". This breaks the chart. It just says "Your browser does not support charts."

Even if you set the document.domain to "test.example.com" (exactly what it is by default), the chart still doesn't work. As far as I can tell, Google Charts is creating an iframe in IE8 and by changing the document.domain at all you are triggering the same-origin security policy to fire.

Because I don't control the Google Libraries I can't set the document.domain on the iframe itself (as I now am not authorized to access it from the upper page, where I have JavaScript). Any ideas on how to solve this problem while still maintaining the ability to change the document.domain?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.domain = "example.com";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still don't have a solution to the root cause. But what we ended up doing was just pushing back the setting of the document.domain property until after the Google chart has been rendered on the page. Then you can set document.domain without causing problems.

Obviously this isn't going to work if you're adding/removing charts from the page dynamically, but for the vast majority of the situations it should.